# getting raw command line arguments in node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line

How can I get the raw command line arguments in a node.js app,
given this example command:

`node forwardwithssh.js echo "hello arguments"`

`process.argv` will be  `[ "node", "/path/to/forwardwith.js", "echo", "hello arguments" ]`

And there's no way to reconstruct the original `echo "hello arguments"` from that (ie. `join(" "` won't put quotes back).
I want the whole original raw string after the script name.

what I want is easily obtained in bash scripts with `"$*"`, is there any equivalent way to get that in node.js?

Note: the intention in particular is to receive a command to be executed somewhere else (eg. thru ssh)

Comment: This module should be able to do what you want: https://www.npmjs.org/package/minimist

Comment: There is no way to tell if the original argument was specified as `"hello arguments"`, `'hello arguments'` or `hello\ arguments`. Those are all the same in bash. Do you want to just always assume that an arg with a space was originally quoted with double quotes? It's easy to see that the space must have been escaped somehow, because you get one arg instead of two for "hello arguments".

Comment: You could quote all your args `process.argv.map(function(arg){ return '"' + arg + '"'; });`. Which will give you: `"node" "forwardwithssh.js" "echo" "hello arguments"`, which is the exact same in bash as your original command .

Comment: @BrianGlaz minimist has the same problem, you can see after the `--` the arguments are parsed too.
@Paulpro I can just add quotes to everything, I want to forward the raw argument as a command to be executed somewhere else

Comment: @Paulpro "$*" in bash does gives u the exact raw string (which I need as it is another command), doesn't just put quotes everywhere

Comment: @Benja That's because bash doesn't know the difference between quotes everywhere and no quotes.

Comment: There are config options you can use to change the behavior.

Comment: @Benja See my answer now. The quotes around the other args like `node` itself are perfectly fine as bash doesn't see any difference between `'node'` and `node`. I opted for single quotes though, since double quotes could break if there were special bash characters like `$` in your arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap each of the args in single quotes, and escape and single quotes within each arg to `'\''`:

```
var cmd_string = process.argv.map( function(arg){
  return "'" + arg.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'";
}).join(' ');
```

That would give you a `cmd_string` containing:

```
'node' '/path/to/forwardwith.js' 'echo' 'hello arguments'
```

which can be run directly in another shell.

Comment: I was afraid adding single quotes wouldn't work on shell, but you're right, I would like to now have to deal with escaping, and be able to log the original command... but this seems to be the best solution available

Comment: It does not give original command arguments. 'node x.js y' and 'node x.js "y"' will give the same process.argv.

Comment: @wandalen Those are evaluated identically in a shell before `node` is even invoked. If you want to pass quotes in from a shell you would need `node x.js \'y\'` or `node x.js "'y'"`.

Comment: @Paulpro goal is not passing quotes but getting original invocation which could be made not by shell. But you are write, I feel it's not possible on Unix-like systems. Windows has [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx).